# Texmaker stopped compiling documents

Tags: xetex, texmaker

Recently (sometime in the last few weeks, not sure exactly as was working with different files) my markdown files no longer compile with Texmaker. As far as I can tell the issue is around `\usepackage` as this is where errors are thrown, and `.sty` files are asked for instead of loading from the package. For example,

`\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools}`

Returns

`!LaTeX Error: File newunicode.sty not found...`

If I try compiling documents using TeXworks then they compile fine. I'm using 5.1.3 on Windows compiling with XeLaTeX. Since Texmaker is my preferred interface (and this problem is irritating because I haven't changed anything since working with these files) I'd like to try get this sorted. An example of a document that doesn't compile in Texmaker but does in TeXworks is

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{newunicodechar,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lineno}

%%% For the literature cited %%%
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}  %% if want numbers change here
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{Literature Cited}}
% Remove comma before year
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}

%%% Line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

%%% Paragraph indentation
\parindent 0.3in

%%% References to figures and tables
\usepackage{prettyref}
\newrefformat{fig}{Fig.~\ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{table}{Table~\ref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\title{Such a great title}
\author{}
\maketitle

Such amazing words

\end{document}
```

Update: showing config settings following @frabjous's comment

[image: Texmaker]

[image: Texworks]

Comment: Welcome. // Looks like you don’t use newunicodechar … so why not discarding this package? However, to use it must be installed on your system.

Comment: if I take that package out it just flags the next one along. It's consistent across files that whatever packages are at the top get flagged as the problem, even though all files have previously compiled fine

Comment: The editors don't compile the documents. They call the external programs, and the external programs compile the documents. Do you have mulitple TeX distributions installed so that they might be calling different versions of xelatex? Can you show us the commands set for each editor (In my version of texmaker: Options > Configure texmaker > Commands; In texworks: Edit > Preferences > Typesetting > XeLaTeX)?

Comment: texmaker and texworks are just editors you are using to write the file, if it works on one but not the other, they are (most likely) using different tex installations and you should simply install newunicode package using your tex system (texlive or miktex)

Comment: Thanks for adding the pictures, but we need to see the actual commands being run. The texmaker for xelatex it's scrolled so you can't see the start. For texworks, you need to double click the entry on the list to get the popup with the command. However, it looks like TeXworks is using `C:\Users\crouc\AppData\Local\Programs\MikTeX\miktex\bin\x64` for executables and texmaker might be looking at `C:\Program Files\MikTeX\miktex\bin\x64` instead. Are those two different MikTeX installations? What if you put the full path to the executables under `C:\User` in for the texmaker commands?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying.

I changed the part of TexMaker from 
`xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
to
`C:/Users/crouc/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64`

which is the same as texworks, but the problem remained. I think this is what was requested